# Finding no of ways to select identical objects

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

If there are 10 notes of 10 dollars . Then no of ways to take 1 note is 10.I.e $10C_1.$

but I think it should be 1 since all notes are identical

$\frac{10C_1}{10}$

Why am I wrong ?

Comment: Can you reproduce the exact question, if it's from some book ?

Comment: @trueblueanil my teacher gave the Q orally

Comment: Well, notes are not **absolutely** identical, eg they are sure to have serial numbers, so the answer is $10$

Comment: @trueblueanil what if I tell that even serial numbers are identical , then ?

Comment: @user15072279 It depends on the context. Usually if you **select** something it cancels to be identical with unselected species.

Comment: Well, then you can consider the notes to be laid out in a line serially, and the answer will still be 10. The very word **choose** implies some selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are right. The binomial coefficient is used when the objects are distinct. Here you have just one object {10}, e.g. 1 choose 1 is 1.

Equally, you are doing 10 choose 0 as there is no choice to be made. Or, if you have {10,10,...,10}, and do 10 choose 1, you must realize everything is the same and divide what you get by 10, again leading to 1.

Equivalently imagine you choose the first number out of a rearrangement of 10 objects as your method of choosing the number. The answer is the binomial coefficient 10 choose 10 slots for the 10 objects. They are identical so after you’ve chosen the slots they all fall in place. Still, answer is 1.